# Почему после перемещения ImageView фигура не возвращается в свое первоначальное состояние и так и остается навсегда спрятанной?

Tags: android, drag-n-drop, ontouchlistener

Почему после перемещения ImageView фигура не возвращается в свое первоначальное состояние и так и останется навсегда спрятанной? OnDrag не срабатывает.

```
OnTouchListener onTch = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder dsb = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {//.N
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop1");
                    v.startDragAndDrop(clipData, dsb, v, 0);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop2");
                } else {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop3");
                    v.startDrag(clipData, dsb, v, 0);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDragAndDrop4");
                }
               v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "1234");
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

 imV.setOnTouchListener(onTch);
```

Метод OnDrag:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "12");
    int action = event.getAction();
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // do nothing
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "12345");
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "12346");
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "12347");
           ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
           owner.removeView(view);
           ConstraintLayout container = (ConstraintLayout) v;
        container.addView(view);
           view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "12348");
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```